# Does drawing your weapon take an action?

Tags: weapons, actions, savage-worlds, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

Previous versions of *Savage Worlds* explicitly stated that it took one action, and there was the Quick Draw action that turned it into a free action. However, that Edge does not seem to exist in the newest release, and I can't find the rules for drawing your weapon.

In *Savage Worlds: Adventure Edition*, does drawing your weapon take an action?

Answer (score 6):

## Nope.

From page 105 of version 4.1 of the core rules:

> Characters may “ready” up to two items per turn as a free action. Readying means drawing, holstering, or otherwise moving an item into or out of a familiar and easy-toreach location.

Comment: It's worth noting that readying additional weapons, or readying them from a difficult location, is still an action. This differs from SWADE version 3 (where drawing a weapon from a difficult location was a free action, but required a roll) and SWADE version 2 (where drawing weapons was always an action, unless you had Quick Draw and/or Fast Draw).

Comment: @Zadmar Can you clarify what you mean by version 3 and version 2?

Comment: @Thunderforge During the post-Kickstarter release, PEG put out four major rules revisions (now referred to as v1, v2, v3, and v4). The latest rules, and the ones that are currently for sale, are v4.1. Drawing and readying weapons changed repeatedly between versions.

Comment: @Thunderforge SWADE is currently in playtest and undergoing regular updates before it goes to print, which is why it’s only available in PDF (with free updates for owners).

Comment: The version 5.2 is what's gone off to the printers